# Restore/reset Razor syntax highlighting in VS (after installing Dreamweaver)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, razor, syntax-highlighting

After installing Dreamweaver CS6, the syntax highlighting of razor in visual studio 2010 removed and all of codes in my .cshtml files now is black.

How can I reset the razor syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Tools* -> *Import and Export Settings*.  Follow the dialog and you should be able to restore your original settings.

1. Import selected environment settings
2. Select a file from the "Default Settings" list (eg, "General Development Settings", etc)

If that doesn't work (your default settings somehow got overwritten?) then you should be able to find a settings file online and import it.  For example, this blog has an export of the VS default settings available for download:  http://www.notimplementedexception.com/?page_id=14

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work! It seems visual studio can't recognize the type of .cshtml